# sqlite tutorial create and view

Tags: android

I am looking for an example or tutorial for sqlite. What I need to do is put info into the database from an input then on another screen display what has been inputted previously.

I know it's pretty basic stuff but I don't know what to do. (I'm not asking for someone to do it for me just a tutorial that I could learn from

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Google "android sqlite tutorial" gives http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Comment: hi. i,ve tried that. my problem is don't know how to get it to take an input from my edit text rather than having it stored and incrementing by however much.

Comment: Sorry, parse error. You need to provide more information of what you want to do, exactly, what you have tried and why it doesn't work the way you want it. "I've tried that" tells us zero.

Comment: hi.
what i'm trying to do is aweight tracking app. you input a target weight and every day you input your current weight. both these need to be put into a db, then on a seperate screen be able to view these in a list.
i have tried the above which only adds the data that is in the code, not allowing for user input. i have tried adding an edit text but with no luck

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial) might be useful.

**EDIT**

An example from one of my projects:

in my datacollection class:

```
private EditText titleText;
private EditText descText;

private String title;
private String desc;

titleText = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
descText = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.desc);

commit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {public void onClick(View v) {
    title = titleText.getText().toString();
    desc = descText.getText().toString();
    mDbHelper.createEventType(title, desc);
}
```

in my dbhelper class:

```
public long createEventType(String eventType, String eventTypeDesc) {
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(EVENTTYPE_NAME, eventType);
    initialValues.put(EVENTTYPE_DESC, eventTypeDesc);
    return mDb.insertWithOnConflict(EVENTTYPE_TABLE, null, initialValues,
            SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
}
```

Comment: this sample isn't good fx `getContact(int id)` will throw errors in some cases ... we don't need `Contact` class for using SQLite ...

Comment: selvin what sample would you suggest?

Comment: i have to agree with selvin here. this one is not doing it for me. i need something that shows me how to get data from a text field that the user has inputted.

Comment: See my edited answer, it ought to show you what you need to know.